# Using CR subreports for displaying two distinct reports in one blank main report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, reporting

I have written a sql query for a view that return some information but when grouping in a CR report some data gets mixed and exact data is lost. what i did is to create two reports when testing, each report return the data i want ( one report for canceling fees and other for earnings ). I then had the idea to create two subreports for each correct report and display both of them in a main report. both report use a SQL view and have formula fied which filter some dates.

When i try to display those subreport in a report all i get is a blank report with no data. i tried to link those subreport with a field but eventough. no data was shown.

Could someone point me some track for getting this work ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: don't link sub reports instead link main report to two sub reports. are you getting data when you individually ruun these reports? Have you checked the sql query those reports generated?

Comment: Hello Siva, Yes i get the data i want when i run each of them. now i want these two report to be merged in one report, that's why i thought of using subreport.

Comment: You don't give enough information: do your subreports have parameters? Are you creating those parametersin your main report, and passing them to the subreports?

Comment: Hello JotaBe. Actually the indvidual report return some data based on the same formula fields ( both select a date range and a value and based on those information they return some data ) what i want to do is to create a report showing those two reports. is that clear enough ? thank you

Comment: As per your input it looks like you have done the process correctly.. may be you need to check filtering date formula field may be that is creating the problem... I would suggest you to run the main report and check the query generated against the database to see whether the generated query is producing results in your database.

Comment: the main report.. i want it to be a blank one containing those subreports generations canceling fees and earning is that possible ? or i should link main report with a subreport with some formula.. sorry if i'm not able to clarify my problem since i'm too new to subreports